# Transforming data returned while using jQuery's Autocomplete function

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to use the [Autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) to produce a search box similar to the one at [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/), I want it to:

- Show more than just text in the options.
- To act like a link when an option is selected (as each option will be a unique record).
- That, if the user chooses, they press the button and a search is performed on their input.

The docs say that there are 3 types of datasource it will work with:

> A data source can be:
>
> an Array with local data
> a String, specifying a URL
> a Callback

I can get the autocomplete to work with the 2nd option, but then there isn't the ability to transform the data returned, it just takes the JSON and puts it straight in the dropdown. This means the source url can only return data in the format `{label: "blah", value: "blurg"}`.

If I could inject a transformation function, then I could have the url return whatever JSON I like, the function would change the data into the format the autocomplete expects but also formatted as I wish, and all without changing the response served by the url (I'm not going to return HTML from there, only JSON).

e.g. The url could return this:

```
{ label:"Grosse Point Blank", id: 3, img:"/imgs/gpb.png",...}
```

and a transform function could mung it into something like this:

```
{ label:"<a href='/films/3/grosse-point-blank'><img src='/imgs/gpb.png' />Grosse Point Blank</a>", value="grosse-point-blank"}
```

I've tried using option 3, a callback, with a `getJSON` call, but I can't get it to work. The nearest code I've found to what I may need is [here, but it has options that aren't listed in the current docs for Autocomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296411/pass-value-returned-from-jqueryui-autocomplete-to-another-function) and I don't understand how to use the response object.

Is there an example of using the callback method with an AJAX request, or how I can inject a function that transforms the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `_renderItem()` private method of autocomplete to format the return data. It looks like this:

```
$("#element").autocomplete({...}).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    //...
};
```

You can see the method definition here https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L520

An example of code that I have used:

```
$("#element").autocomplete({...})
.data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li></li>" ) // create the list item
        .data( "item.autocomplete", item ) // save the data to the DOM
        .append( "<a>"+ item.label + "</a>" ) // add the HTML
        .appendTo( ul ); // append to the UL
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a brief structure when using callback method.

```
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      ...
      success: function( data ) {
        // do transformation of data here
        response(data);          
      }
    });
  }
```

Quoted from your link, http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

> The third variation, the callback, provides the most flexibility, and
> can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete. The callback
> gets two arguments:
>
> A request object, with a single property called "term", which refers
> to the value currently in the text input. For example, when the user
> entered "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal
> "new yo".
>
> A response callback, which expects a single argument to
> contain the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered
> based on the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described
> above for simple local data (String-Array or Object-Array with
> label/value/both properties). It's important when providing a custom
> source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always
> call the response callback even if you encounter an error. This
> ensures that the widget always has the correct state.

Comment: This is technically correct, but the data is expected to be in a particular format for it to be rendered properly. I would opt to use `_renderItem()` to change the display format and modify any data that you want to attach to the DOM. The exception being if you need to loop through all the return data to change items conditionally.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. We go through each item and modify it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I'm going to look into all the stuff you've suggested and let you know what works. I really appreciate the help, it's already opened my eyes to a few things.

Comment: I actually ended up using both, ace's answer helped me with munging the returned data, but I gave the tick to doublesharp because then I was able to render the data as I'd asked. Many thanks to you both, I wish I could give you both the full points.